# Not all arguments converted error in python string format

Tags: python

while executing the following, receiving this error. can you please let me know how to fix this

content[1] has the date value read from csv file which is in this format 7/23/2013

```
d2 = datetime.strptime('%s' % (content[1].strip('\n')), '%m/%d/%Y')
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Try `d2 = datetime.strptime("7/23/2013", '%m/%d/%Y')`?

Comment: So, is it day/month/year as you mention in the above comment, or month/day/year as in "7/23/2013"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard you like formatting, but you don't need to put formatting in your formatting. Leave out the `%s` part and use the month/day/year format that you say Excel is giving you:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("7/23/2013", '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Included the complete code snippet now. please check

Comment: @SudheerG - Your new question is entirely, substantively different from the original question. Accept your preferred answer for that original question if you wish, and then ask your new question _in a new question_, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people know what the issue is.

Comment: could not post a new question. updated the question above to acknowledge the answer to first question and expanded on the actual issue. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the arguments of `strptime` is strptime(time_string, format_string), such as:
`datetime.strptime('7/23/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')`
more details here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime